# Render gets darker - after being rendered

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, light, color

I'm building up my portfolio, but when rendering an image, it got darker - after it was rendered. see the screenshots to see what I mean.[image]

[image]

Notice the difference in contrast between the 2? the one above is still being rendered, and the second one is seconds after the first one.. Anyone knows what could be causing this, and how to fix it?

I have tried rendering in both Evee and Cycles, with the same result. These are my lighting settings..

[image]

Comment: What's your lamp type, sun or point?

Comment: It's a sun, with a strength of 2.5

Comment: Fixed it, after playing with some settings in the renderer :) Here's what i did: changed "Composite" to view layer at the rendered image and then to "combined". Thanks anyway

Comment: That's great, All the best!